# Polari connect to bouncer with custom port

Tags: gnome, irc

Polari doesn't have much to go on in the way of documentation. I'm trying to connect to my ZNC bouncer, which uses a non-standard IRC port. When I try connecting the XChat/HexChat (irc.domain.tld/port) way it just errors out and when I use the standard host-port format (irc.domain.tld:port) it just infinitely tries to connect. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `mc-tool` (Mission Control accounts tool) to manage Telepathy Idle accounts. Idle is the name of the IRC plug-in for the Telepathy framework used by Polari. This command should be available from the terminal window.

Create an account setting for your server, e.g.:

```
mc-tool add idle/irc SomeCoolNet string:account=mynickname string:server=irc.domain.tld
```

Replace `irc.domain.tld` with your own ZNC server domain. Replace `SomeCoolNet` with your desired display network name (as visible in the Polari network list on the sidebar).

Then for that `mynickname` account, it will create a mangled name, usually `idle/irc/mynickname0`. Then:

```
mc-tool list
```

Should display the list of Telepathy accounts to get the mangled name you need for the next step. Finally:

```
mc-tool update idle/irc/mynickname0 string:username=mynickname/mynetwork string:password=myzncpassword bool:use-ssl=true uint:port=6697 bool:password-prompt=false
```

Here replace `idle/irc/mynickname0` if needed. The username is the usual username/network in ZNC, replace it with your own. And finally, replace the custom port from the example from `6697` to something else. If you don't use SSL (you should!), remove the `bool:use-ssl=true`.

After this, remember to quit Polari with Control+Q, not closing the window, as it could continue running on background. After reopening it, it should display the new network. It could need to require connect/reconnect the first time.